# Immersive Mode with toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-immersive

I am trying to enter in immersive mode using

```
View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

this hides the toolbar but when exiting using

```
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

toolbar doesnt reappear,
If I force the toolbar show using

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
```

toolbar is partially hidden behind status bar. So how would I make toolbar reappear again correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Try below method to toggle immersive mode, This method is from google sample and used with fragment, change it accordingly if you are using for activity.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ImmersiveMode/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/immersivemode/ImmersiveModeFragment.java

```
public void toggleHideBar() {

        int uiOptions = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
        boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled =
                ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);
        if (isImmersiveModeEnabled) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Turning immersive mode mode off. ");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Turning immersive mode mode on.");
        }

        // Navigation bar hiding:  Backwards compatible to ICS.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        }

        // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        }

        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
        //END_INCLUDE (set_ui_flags)
    }
```

Comment: already tried that, Its jerks the UI, also neither hides the nor shows toolbar